# Gradient Descent Algorithm using Pandas + GIF Visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, machine-learning

Happy new year everyone, Following [Andrew NG's course on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/) here's my implementation for the gradient descent algorithm(univariate linear regression) in Python using pandas, matplotlib with optional visualization which creates a GIF. Any optimizations/suggestions are welcome.

For those who don't know what gradient descent algorithm is: Gradient descent is a first-order iterative optimization algorithm for finding the local minimum of a function. To find a local minimum of a function using gradient descent, one takes steps proportional to the negative of the gradient (or approximate gradient) of the function at the current point. If, instead, one takes steps proportional to the positive of the gradient, one approaches a local maximum of that function. You can check the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) on wikipedia.

**Ex1 GIF:**

[image: GIF 1]

**Ex2 GIF:**

[image: GIF 2]

Links for the datasets used:

**ex1:**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tztcXVillZTrbPeeCd28djRooM5nkiBZ

**ex2:**

https://drive.google.com/open?id=17ZQ4TLA7ThtU-3J-G108a1fzCH72nSFp

**CODE**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
import imageio
import os


def compute_cost(b, m, data):
    """
    Compute cost function for univariate linear regression using mean squared error(MSE).
    Args:
        b: Intercept (y = mx + b).
        m: Slope (y = mx + b).
        data: A pandas df with x and y data.
    Return:
         Cost function value.
    """
    data['Mean Squared Error(MSE)'] = (data['Y'] - (m * data['X'] + b)) ** 2
    return data['Mean Squared Error(MSE)'].sum().mean()


def adjust_gradient(b_current, m_current, data, learning_rate):
    """
    Adjust Theta parameters for the univariate linear equation y^ = hθ(x) = θ0 + θ1x
    Args:
        b_current: Current Intercept (y = mx + b) or [Theta(0) θ0].
        m_current: Current Slope (y = mx + b) or [Theta(1) θ1].
        data: A pandas df with x and y data.
        learning_rate: Alpha value.
    Return:
        Adjusted Theta parameters.
    """
    data['b Gradient'] = -(2 / len(data)) * (data['Y'] - ((m_current * data['X']) + b_current))
    data['m Gradient'] = -(2 / len(data)) * data['X'] * (data['Y'] - ((m_current * data['X']) + b_current))
    new_b = b_current - (data['b Gradient'].sum() * learning_rate)
    new_m = m_current - (data['m Gradient'].sum() * learning_rate)
    return new_b, new_m


def gradient_descent(data, b, m, learning_rate, max_iter, visual=False):
    """
    Optimize Theta values for the univariate linear regression equation y^ = hθ(x) = θ0 + θ1x.
    Args:
        data: A pandas df with x and y data.
        b: Starting b (θ0) value.
        m: Starting m (θ1) value.
        learning_rate: Alpha value.
        max_iter: Maximum number of iterations.
        visual: If True, a GIF progression will be generated.
    Return:
        Optimized values for θ0 and θ1.
    """
    line = np.arange(len(data))
    folder_name = None
    if visual:
        folder_name = str(random.randint(10 ** 6, 10 ** 8))
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
        os.chdir(folder_name)
    for i in range(max_iter):
        b, m = adjust_gradient(b, m, data, learning_rate)
        if visual:
            data['Line'] = (line * m) + b
            data.plot(kind='scatter', x='X', y='Y', figsize=(8, 8), marker='x', color='r')
            plt.plot(data['Line'], color='b')
            plt.grid()
            plt.title(f'y = {m}x + {b}\nCurrent cost: {compute_cost(b, m, data)}\nIteration: {i}\n'
                      f'Alpha = {learning_rate}')
            fig_name = ''.join([str(i), '.png'])
            plt.savefig(fig_name)
            plt.close()
    if visual:
        frames = os.listdir('.')
        frames.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
        frames = [imageio.imread(frame) for frame in frames]
        imageio.mimsave(folder_name + '.gif', frames)
    return b, m


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    data.columns = ['X', 'Y']
    learning = 0.00001
    initial_b, initial_m = 0, 0
    max_it = 350
    b, m = gradient_descent(data, initial_b, initial_m, learning, max_it, visual=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Nothing happens!

When I ran the script my first thought was that it had hung because
nothing happened. Apparently the calculations are just slow on my
computer.

To reassure the user that the program is working, have some output
indicating progress. Here's how I added it, but you can make it way
fancier with progress bars and stuff:

```
n_reports = 20
for i in range(max_iter):
    if max_iter >= n_reports and i % (max_iter // n_reports) == 1:
        print(f'{(i * 100 // max_iter)}% ', end = '', flush = True)
    ...
print('100%')
```

`n_reports` is the number of times the completion percentage is
printed. An impatient user wants it printed more often, a patient one
(or one with a faster computer) wants it printed less often.

#### Temporary directories

Python has a module for temporary files and directories which you
should use instead of creating your own. Also, never change the
process current working directory (the `chdir` call) unless you have
to. It can cause very strange problems.

The `tempfile` and `pathlib` modules simplifies file handling:

```
if visual:
    save_dir = pathlib.Path(tempfile.mkdtemp())
...
for i in range(max_iter):
    ...
    if visual:
        ...
        fig_name = f'{i:05}.png'
        plt.savefig(save_dir / fig_name)
...
if visual:
    frames = sorted([f.resolve() for f in save_dir.iterdir()])
    frames = [imageio.imread(frame) for frame in frames]
    image_file = save_dir.name + '.gif'
    imageio.mimsave(image_file, frames)
    print(f'Saved image as {image_file}')
```

I also made it so that filenames are padded with zeroes. That way, you
can rely on the lexicographical order and you don't have to write your
own key function.

Comment: What does the `flush = True` in the print statement do? and does the temporary directory (with the .png frames) disappear after the execution and if so, where the .gif file will be saved? and what do you think of the implementation of the algorithm? any suggestions you have regarding how to optimize close to `sklearn` auto-optimization done by the `LinearRegression()`?

Comment: It flushes so that the output becomes visible despite lacking an ending newline character. The temporary directory has to be removed with `shutil.rmtree(save_dir)`. The gif is saved in the current directory. Your gradient descent implementation is fine, but lacks learning rate scheduling and early stoppage (detection if an optima is reached). Of course, it is not the right tool for the job and there are better methods for univariate linear regression.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I know using `LinearRegression()` is sufficient for the job, I've done it for the sake of understanding how things work as i'm following Andrew NG's course(which is done in Octave and Matlab) so I have to convert everything I learn to Python.